# Tkinter maximum number of widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

I've got quite a complicated GUI interface built by Tkinter library. It has several tabs and a lot of controls with possibility of dynamic adding and deleting them.

And it seems that Tkinter has an internal maximum number of widgets, something about 10000 (including Frames). When it is exceeded new widgets are not created and even some strange graphical effects can appear outside the window (without any exceptions or messages).

Did anyone face such problems? I wonder if there is a way to overcome this limitation.

Comment: The way to overcome this is to build your GUI in such a way that it updates widgets with new information rather than making new ones. Instead of a scrolled box with 100,000 Entry widgets in it, only make enough Entry widgets to fill the screen, and then connect the scroll bar to some code to update them.

Comment: There should always be a way to work around the widget limitation. Like @Novel mentioned you can write your code in a way that updates your widgets rather than needed many thousands of them.

Comment: I can't imagine needing 10,000 widgets. I don't think I can imagine using 1,000, unless perhaps you're creating a grid of tiny buttons. I've written quite complex production level GUIs with tk and never came close to hitting any sort of limit.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you hear about the 10,000 widget limit?

Comment: Nowhere previously. I just see that after ~10,000 new widgets cannot be produced and furthermore the whole GUI breaks at all.
About @Novel advice - I don't believe that it is possible (or maybe I don't have enough experience for that). It's a very specific data science software and every input is unique.

Comment: If you provide a minimal working example of how you have it set up now we will lend our expertise to help you improve it.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I create 3n^2-3n+1 text boxes arranged in a hexagon. It works up to n=12. Beyond that, it does not display anything.

Comment: I am facing the same issue exactly.
Is the limit for 10000 widgets that live simultaneously or can you let some get garbage collected and create more, passing the 10000, but not at the same time?

Comment: I filed a bug about it (https://bugs.python.org/issue41632). The Python devs found that it happens in TCL as well, so they closed it as 'thirdparty'.

Comment: For people searching for this - I encountered a similar problem where I had a scrolled box with many widgets. After much searching the problem seems to be the limit placed on the number of USER Handles (10000) a process can have. The number of USER Handles can be seen with Process Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, there is a way to have more than 10000 widgets, but not simultaneously.

If you destroy() the widgets you don't currently need, you can have more than 10000 during the lifetime of the application.

Application needs don't always allow it, but in your case, maybe you could destroy the unused tabs while they are not selected?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. In that case was not appropriate. The problem was solved by migration to PyQt =)

Answer (score 0):

I have reached a similar problem. (migrating to QT is way too bothersome for me at the moment)

My solution is to "paginate" the data shown, so I can have a fixed number of widgets and just rewrite them based on the page I'm on.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this explanation may solve the question, including a sample code of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. I suggest you to edit your answer to add some code example, Have a look here → [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Thanks!